# Vulkan image incompatibility, is there a nice way to check which parameters are incompatible?

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan, validation-layers

My validation errors are returning the following error:

```
Message ID name: VUID-VkImageCreateInfo-imageCreateMaxMipLevels-02251
Message: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkImageCreateInfo-imageCreateMaxMipLevels-02251 ] Object 0: handle = 0x1867f53a780, name = Logical device: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xbebcae79 | vkCreateImage(): Format VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB is not supported for this combination of parameters and VkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties returned back VK_ERROR_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED. The Vulkan spec states: Each of the following values (as described in Image Creation Limits) must not be undefined : imageCreateMaxMipLevels, imageCreateMaxArrayLayers, imageCreateMaxExtent, and imageCreateSampleCounts (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.198.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkImageCreateInfo-imageCreateMaxMipLevels-02251)
Severity: VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT
```

I know exactly the place in the code that's causing this, however I don't know which combination of parameters is at fault. Is there a way to get the driver to indicate:

"Your image is format x which is incompatible with usage type y" or something like that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the error, but it seems like one of the arguments is `nullptr`.

Comment: No, the issue is the format I am trying to use is not supported in combination with other settings, so the object I want to make cannot be created.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to have the driver tell me which settings are explicitly clashing rather than trying to do an educated guess.

Comment: @Makogan; It gave you four variables, at least one of which causing the problem. Can you not simply breakpoint at the place you know where this is coming from and look at them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some parameters are clashing, then ask https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues for improved error reporting. There should ideally be appropriate error message.

But if the GPU simply does not support given combination of parameters, then there is nothing that can be done. It is meaningles to ask "why don't you support X". They simply don't, because it is not implemented or not implementable on given GPU\driver.

Comment: I am not asking for the support. I would like to get a message like:

"You are using this format and this usage flag, both those are incompatible".

I.e. don;t just tell me that I am doing something invalid, tell me the combination of paramters that triggered the valdation error.

Comment: @Makogan: That is, this is not an error you should ever see, and if you do see it, its because you did something else wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is correct I did something wrong. What I want is for the api to tell me what I did wrong so that I can undo the wrong thing I did. It's absurdly pedantic to say "it's not supposed to be a nice API" all APIs are supposed to be "nice". In that they try to solve  a specific problem as best as possible and give people as many tools to solve bugs as is reasonable.

That assessment is opinionated and unhelpful. Either this can be enforced and it's useful to do so, or it cannot be enforced, or not enough demand exists to justify it.

Comment: @Makogen You are asking for error reporting enhancement. If you are not asking for support, then what exactly are you asking for? If you are trying to use e.g. `VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT` with `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT`, then by all means let the layers say so. (But you are speaking to the general community, and as such asking at the wrong place). But if the driver does not support a format, it does not support it because of the **whole** combination of parameters is unsupported. There is nothing more to report there other than it is unsupported.